# Counting occurrences of a word in a string with Javascript using match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to count occurrences of each word in longer text using the `match` method, but instead of `result` I get only an error:

> Cannot read property 'length' of null

My function looks like this:

```js
const myText = "cat dog stop rain cat"

myText.split(" ").forEach((word) => {
  const numberOfOccurrences = myText.match(/word/g).length
  console.log(`${word} - ${numberOfOccurrences}`)
})
```

How can I repair it to get the proper result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The regular expression is literally matching `word`, as variable `word` is never indicated. There is no match found in the string `myText` so it's null, hence the error. Try like this:

```
myText.match(new RegExp(word, "g")).length
```

This uses the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor, which takes in two arguments: the pattern and the flags. The above will pass the actual value of `word` instead of the literal `word`, and the flag `g`. It's equivalent to `/word/g` except `word` is correctly matched to what `word` is passed. See the following snippet:

```js
const myText = "cat dog stop rain cat"

myText.split(" ").forEach((word) => {
  const numberOfOccurrences = myText.match(new RegExp(word, "g")).length
  console.log(`${word} - ${numberOfOccurrences}`)
})
```

As others have pointed out, there are better ways to do this. The output of your code above outputs the occurrence of `cat` twice, because it occurs twice. I would recommend saving your counts in an object and updating the counts at each pass, which [ibrahim mahrir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42334131/5647260) shows in their answer. The idea is to use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to iterate over the split array, and reduce with the initial value of an empty object. Then, the empty object is updated with the counts of the word added by one, with initial count of zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try simple solution with **`Array#filter`**, without using `RegExp` and **`Array#match`**.

```js
var text = "cat dog stop rain cat";
var textArr = text.split(' ');
var arr = [...new Set(text.split(' '))];

arr.forEach(v => console.log(`${v} appears: ${textArr.filter(c => c == v).length} times`));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because nothing is matched. There is no word `word` in your string. Try this:

```js
const myText = "cat dog stop rain cat"

myText.split(" ").forEach((word) => {
  const numberOfOccurrences = myText.match(new RegExp(word, 'g')).length;
  console.log(`${word} - ${numberOfOccurrences}`)
})
```

**Without regular expressions:**

Use a hash object like this:

```js
const myText = "cat dog stop rain cat"

var result = myText.split(" ").reduce((hash, word) => {
  hash[word] = hash[word] || 0;
  hash[word]++;
  return hash;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression returns an array, which has one entry, hence it always returns 1. You also have to create a regexp from the word because match takes a regexp and not a string as its argument.

Try this instead

```js
const myText = "cat dog stop word rain cat"

myText.split(" ").forEach((word) => {
  const numberOfOccurrences = myText.match(new RegExp(word, 'g')).length;
  console.log(`${word} - ${numberOfOccurrences}`)
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by *Your expression returns an array, which has one entry, hence it always returns 1*?

Answer (score 0):

I think your example is just trying to match the literal `word`. You should use `RegExp(word, "gi"` instead.

```
const myText = "cat dog stop rain cat"

myText.split(" ").forEach((word) => {
  const numberOfOccurrences = myText.match(RegExp(word, "gi")).length
  console.log(`${word} - ${numberOfOccurrences}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with above answer but if in case you looking with array of strings this will do

```
var textArr = ['apple', 'mango' ,'apple', 'apple' ,'cherry'];
var arr = [...new Set(textArr)];

arr.forEach(v => console.log(`${v} appears: ${textArr.filter(c => c == v).length} times`));
```